# Viewing Scaladoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, scaladoc

In **Eclipse** I have set the *Javadoc Location* property of my Scala project to `file:/D:/EclipseWorkspace/MyProject/target/scala-2.9.1/api` where `D:/EclipseWorkspace/MyProject` is the location of my scala project.

Now, if I am in a Scala file that implements a class/trait, when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, Eclipse opens the Scaladoc page of that class/trait. However, this does not work if it is an object since Eclipse tries to open `<ObjectName>.html` whereas the Scaladoc-generated file name is `<ObjectName>$.html`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: AFAIK, no. In fact, even _inside Scaladoc itself_ one cannot link to objects. If you look at the pages I wrote, like Regex or the stuff inside scala.sys.process, you'll see the convoluted way I refer to them, instead of simply linking to them. Mind you, I'm not claiming Scaladoc's limitation has anything to do with Eclipse's limitation.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral. Thanks. If it doesn't work in Scaladoc itself, one can not expect it to work with eclipse javadoc mechanism. I was just hoping that if we know the mangled names of the generated 
class files for the objects then we can somehow trick Eclipse to open the corresponding html. (This will be just a temporary workaround since the mangled names might change in future versions of scala/scaladoc) 

The ideal way would be scaladoc supports object links and then Scala-IDE overrides `Shift-F2`

Comment: Having tried a few different setups of Eclipse and scala versions, I've never been able to get anything more than code completion to operate, and have often wondered how (if possible) to see JavaDoc information in realtime

Comment: The scaladoc intergration is mentioned in this issue: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000860 It seems it's still a while before it's added.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scaladoc is now integrated since [release 4.0.0 RC1](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.0.0-RC1.html) of the Scala-IDE plugin. You can just hover over your term, or press F2 while the cursor is on the identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Typesafe has [announced](http://blog.typesafe.com/genjavadoc-generate-true-javadoc-for-scala-pr) a plugin for the Scala compiler which generates *JavaDoc* for your *Scala* API. The plugin and its documentation is available on [github](https://github.com/typesafehub/genjavadoc). Maybe this helps as a workaround.