# How to view scaladoc as part of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure scaladoc in eclipse juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394471/how-to-configure-scaladoc-in-eclipse-juno)

Having downloaded eclipse and having installed scala plugins, i am now able to run and compile scala programs.

How can i get eclipse to actually show me the scaladoc, similar to how javadoc shows up?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for viewing scaladoc in eclipse  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429817