# When linking to scala, eclipse is showing argument names arg0,arg1,arg2… for methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, autocomplete

I'm writing java code using scala one (Kafka api), and I can't get eclipse to get the argument names in methods autocompletion, it's instead suggesting things like Method(String arg0, int arg1,...)

The source is apparently found correctly, as I can browse into it with F12, and I see the correct argument names, but it's still a bit tedious to go into every function, retrieve the argument names, and write the call after that.

I've installed the scala plugin for eclipse, which did not solve this.

Is is possible to solve this ? If yes, how ?

Thanks !

Comment: Depends AFAIK on the [JavaDoc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7043711/995891) part, not on the sources. (And I have no clue if there is such a thing as javadocs in scala)

Answer (score 0):

I had come across this issue a while ago and was figuring out how to fix it. Eventually used this plugin. You should take a look at his. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520267/614867